# Python Code to monitor and detect changes in website's scraped content/HTML code in current/Real-Time

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I started working on scraping website content and HTML code using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I want a Python code that can store the scraped content or HTML code in current/real-time. Then after a specific manually assigned time interval, the code should execute once again and scrape the content or HTML code of the same website or webpage. And it should then compare both scraped data and show any change occurred. I want this code to monitor changes that happen on a website and report them.

What I have done so far:

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="https://www.uetmardan.edu.pk/uetm/"

# Step1: Get the HTML content
r = requests.get(url)

# Step2: Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

#print(soup.prettify()) # just printing the HTML code

print(soup.get_text()) # just printing the text
```

Comment: Sounds like you know exactly what you want, what's your question?

Comment: This code scrapes the data or content. I know what I want, but the problem is with implementation. I want a code that can perform the above tasks that I mentioned

Comment: Have you attempted to implement what you want, are facing a particular error or issue that you have a question about?

Comment: I am unable to implement because:                                                                                     
              1. I do not know how to store the data that I have scraped in current/real-time.                                                                                                                                   
               2. I do not know how to set a timer over it that can crawl my code after the set intervals

Comment: The timing stuff is simple.  `while True:` / `...do stuff...` / `time.sleep(5*60)`.  The rest depends on what you want to compare.

Comment: Thanks, @TimRoberts, for the solution to the "Timer" problem. Can you also help with the data comparison and change monitoring problem as well?

Comment: YOU HAVE TO KNOW what information you want to monitor.  We can't help with that.  You can, of course, store the whole page into a file, and then compare the entire text at once, but that's probably not too useful.  I assume there are things ON the page that you want to monitor.  We don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple loop? You can even thread it out:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    try:
        #your code#
    except KeyboardInterrupt: #so you can break the loop
        #maybe some clean up
        break
    #maybe catch something else

    sleep(interval)
```

About storing, just make it part of the logic. Use a database or a file or email it. Maybe only store it if there are changes. You have a vast amount of options there.

Comment: Sir, your code's good, but I can still not comprehend how to store data in real-time and compare data to monitor and recognize the change?

Comment: @RomanKhattak to store data you can use standard `open()`, `write()`, `close()` inside `while True:`. As for comparing - it depends what you want to get. If you want only get `True/False` then simply use `old_text == new_text`. If you want check some special element in HTML then use `BeautifulSoup` to get this element and compare it with previous version using again `==`. But all this depend what you have in HTML and which element you want to compare - but you didn't show HTML , nor URL, so we can't help it.

Comment: @furas, my question is very simple, please do not get confused. I want to find any and every change that occurs in a website(content/HTML code). For that, I want a solution. The theoretical solution that I have come upon is that I scrape the website content/ HTML code. Then after some time my code will scrape the data again and compare both data then detect and report each and every change that has happened. But I don't know how to implement this concept. So please help with that if you can.

Comment: @RomanKhattak your question is very simple but real solution can be complex. Problem makes showing changes two pages. It is simple to get page, you check if you  local file with previous version - if you don't have it then save it. next wait/sleep some time or run program again after some time. And next time you again get page, again check if you have local file with previous version - if you have it then load it and compare with current version, display differences, and save new version in local file. And sleep or run program again after some time. Problem is displaying differences.

Comment: @RomanKhattak as I said problem is comparing two files. They may have different length so comparing char-by-char may not show which part changed. You would have to use `BeautifulSoup` to compare elements/tags on page - and it may works if page didn't change structure. All it will need to every element from first file and check if it exists in new file - because elements are nested so it may need also nested `for`-loops or recurection. But if some element was moved from one tag to another (or there are new tags before old tag) then it makes very complex problem.

Comment: @furas thanks a lot for your generous response, but my problem is still active. Can you please give me a clear roadmap as to how I can compare the scraped data at real-time/current time? If I store data into different files and compare the files to monitor changes that will not be a standard and proper method. And if you can also give me some piece of code, that will be more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: if you will run code in `while`-loop then it will check it almost in real-time - but if you will do it too often then server may block you. And if you will run program all time then you can keep data in memory without saving in file.